# JQuery getJSON causing infinite loop

Tags: jquery, getjson, infinite-loop

I can't seem to figure out why this block of code causes an infinite loop.  I suspect that by update the html elements I am causing the load event to be re-triggered and therefore getJSON is called repeatedly.  If that's the case, any suggestions on how to call getJSON when the page (or a specific element loads) without causing the loop?

```
$("#content").on("load",function(){
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
$('#div1').html(data.Name);
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to load this when the DOM is ready (i.e. the page is rendered completely)

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     $('#div1').html(data.Name);
   });
});
```

Comment: I tried using $(document).ready however the result is the same.  After the div1 element is changed the ready event fires again which puts it in an infinite loop.

Comment: Disregard my last comment.  I found the problem, I was experimenting with setInterval and it seems that was causing loop issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reloading the `content` element from `$.getJSON`  , then it will go to infinite loop. I don't know what type is your content element. But I think , dont call it `onload`. Trigger the JSON call on change of something that you are not going to change inside your `$.getJSON`